# System requirements ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, system-requirements

Can my machine with dual intel core i5 1.80GHz, x64 processor and 4 Gb ram, run the newest Ubuntu 20.04? I know that on their official pages is written as the minimal requirements at least 2 GHz, but it seems to me that diffence between 1.8 and 2 isn't too much, but I am not expert. Thank you for your time and answer kind people

Comment: Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements   yes it may run, but it may be slow, thus the reason for the minimum speed.  The kind of processor also has influence (speed of FSB etc) but to keep specs easy 2GHz is the expected minimum for releases Ubuntu 17.10 or later (running GNOME) for good experience.   How patient are you?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 is not the "newest".